# Filter object by key value to get keys of of all affected objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In my data object, there are multiple objects - optional with some dependency data.
First I need to get all elements, with a given key (passed as string array). For this first step, the code is working to filter the give elements.

In the first step I filter two of five elements: `one` and `two`; and the expected result is ['@scope/one', '@scope/two'].

- But `@scope/one` has a `deps` key, so I need to add `three` and `two` also to the result. `@scope/two` is already existing in the result array.
- And `@scope/three` has `four` as deps, which now also has to be added to the result.
- `@scope/four` has no deps, so the loop is finished.

In this example the result should be `['@scope/one', '@scope/two', '@scope/three', '@scope/four']`.

In other words: I need to filter for some elements and then I need to loop for each deps and add this key also to the result array.

```js
const data = {
  '@scope/one': { deps: { three: { foo: 'bar' }, two: { foo: 'bar' } } },
  '@scope/two': { foo: 'bar' },
  '@scope/three': { deps: { four: { foo: 'bar' } } },
  '@scope/four': { foo: 'bar' },
  '@scope/five': { foo: 'bar' },
};

function sanitize(data, whitelist) {
  return whitelist.reduce(
    (result, key) => (data[key] !== undefined ? Object.assign(result, { [key]: data[key] }) : result),
    {}
  );
}

const filtered = sanitize(data, ['one', 'two']);
const result = Object.keys(filtered);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a queue of keys and keep pushing `deps` until the queue is empty:

```js
function pick(obj, keys) {
    let res = new Set(), queue = [...keys]

    while (queue.length) {
        let key = '@scope/' + queue.shift()

        if (!res.has(key)) {
            res.add(key)

            let val = obj[key]
            if (val.deps)
                queue.push(...Object.keys(val.deps))
        }
    }

    return [...res]
}

//

const data = {
    '@scope/one': {deps: {three: {foo: 'bar'}, two: {foo: 'bar'}}},
    '@scope/two': {foo: 'bar'},
    '@scope/three': {deps: {four: {foo: 'bar'}}},
    '@scope/four': {deps: {one: {foo: 'bar'}}}, // cycle!
    '@scope/five': {foo: 'bar'},
};

console.log(pick(data, ['one', 'two']))
```

If circular dependencies are possible, add the `if(!res.has(key))` check to break them.

As a side note, it would look more transparent if `deps` were just key lists rather than full objects.

Comment: Thanks. I missed an important thing: The 'first level' keys have a 'scope' in its name, the deps don't have that. In the result I need always the 'first level' keys with scope. I've updates my post. `let val = obj['@scope/' + key]` seems to be the wrong place... Sorry for missing the scope in the initial post.

Comment: no prob, one minor change: `let key = '@scope/' + queue.shift()`

Comment: I added `if(!res.has(key)) res.add(key)`, but the loops is still infinite

Comment: I still have an infinite loop with my data. I guess the problem is, that we are adding multiple elements in the queue at once and we are only removing one element at the same time. So even if we check for existing elements in the res, there could be multiple cycles, as there could be multiple deps for each element.